# Knockout Computed Subscription to undeclared observable

Tags: knockout.js, subscriptions

Is there any way to manually add or remove a subscription to a knockout computed?  In the scenario that I want to add a subscription to an observable not yet declared, or as a property that could change.

ie:

```
self.myComputed = ko.computed(function() {
   return "Value Is: " + self.myObservable();
})

self.myObservable(1);
//self.myComputed returns "Value Is: 1"
```

then later:

```
self.myObservable = ko.observable(2);  //new observable to property
//some code to add subscription to self.myComputed here
self.myObservable(3);
//self.myComputed returns "Value Is: 3" now
```

I realize that there's ways around the issue (such as simply reusing self.myObservable for the next value) but I would sometimes like to manually tinker with the subscriptions.

Comment: the subscriptions for a computed observable are registered at declaration to the actual observable object, not the name of the property on the view model - you can only update the value of the subscribed observable for the computed to pick it up. The alternative would be to recreate the computed after you've made any changes to your observable structure to generate new subscriptions to the new observables.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  That is absolutely true.  In the case of that you'd also want to make sure to manually dispose the computed before creating a new one as well.

Comment: You could potentially make `self.myObservable` an observable of observable. So you'd do something like `self.observable = ko.observable(ko.observable(1)); self.myComputed = ko.computed(function(){ return "value is: " + ko.unwrap(self.observable()); }); self.observable(ko.observable(3));`. Works technically; however, I must say I'm not sure I really understand the use case (but I don't need to, as long as you do :)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
There is not currently a use case I'm going against, just something I've thought of in the past, where I'd perhaps like to create an object and move it through a series of inputs, before ultimately ending in an array or something, with a reusable "flow" for a new object.  It's just as easy to create the new object at the end and reset the observable values however.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see why you'd want to do this, but you could create a computed that references an observable by property name, rather than value.

```
self.myComputed = function () {
    return "Value is "+self["myObservable"]();
};
self.myObservable(1);
self.myComputed(); // Returns "Value is 1"

var oldMyObservable = self.myObservable;
self.myObservable = ko.observable(2);
self.myComputed(); // Returns "Value is 1", since the computed hasn't updated

oldMyObservable.notifySubscribers(); //force myComputed to recompute
self.myComputed(); // Returns "Value is 2"
```

Granted, I think the approach of an observable containing an observable is cleaner; but I thought the approach above was interesting enough to post.